# Bild vergrößern mit Fancybox

Tags: fancybox, modx

I use ModX and would like to change the size of a displayed image under "fancybox". However, I can not find the CSS file in which the details are.

[Code-Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw2BL.png)

The "element.style" can be seen in the picture. This is likely to be created. What I want to change is the "width: 494px;" To adjust the overall size of the image. Where can I find that ?

Comment: Sorry for the title. "Change the picturesize in fancybox".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change that `width` - than change it in fancybox options - http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Is this the "jquery.fancybox.pack.js" file?

Comment: You need to find your `$("a[rel='fancybox'']").fancybox({});` callback and change it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if you need further help with that. You can and should use *pthumb* for the resizing and caching before passing into a slider or lightbox tool.

pthumb is the fork of phpthumbof.
https://modx.com/extras/package/pthumb